# Unable to delete identity in Keychain

Tags: macos, command-line, security, keychain

A certificate that we use for Wi-Fi in the office has expired, and it does not renew for some reason. I tried to delete it from the Keychain Access I get the following error:

[image: Invalid Keychain]

I guess that's the reason why the certificate is not being renewed.

I tried the same from terminal as well. When I try to find it using its name, it finds and shows that it is not valid.

```bash
$> security find-identity  "XXXXXXXoffice"  /Users/username/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db


Policy: X.509 Basic
  Matching identities
  1) F0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX30 "localhost" (CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED)
  2) E9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXC9 "4ab2f0ae-76fd-4636-a899-c4e89b8386d1" (CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED)
     2 identities found

  Valid identities only
     0 valid identities found
```

When I try to delete it though, I get an error, just like I get from the Keychain Access.

```bash
security delete-identity -c "XXXXXXXoffice"  /Users/username/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
Unable to delete certificate matching "XXXXXXXoffice"%
```

Any suggestions on how I can delete this keychain identity?

Comment: Can I ask what version of macOS you're running? Also, can you clarify *why* you don't want to reset your Keychain? Doing so often resolves Keychain issues.

Comment: Because the login chain contains other items as well, not just this one. I only want to delete one identity in it.

Comment: I am running macOS 12.5 Monterey.

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar problem like yours and a solution at [Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7357200?answerId=29398789022#29398789022).

Hope it helps.

In time, this is the solution posted at Apple Community:

> Certain files have a property incorrectly set that will prevent them from being changed or deleted while the system is running. That property can only be removed in Recovery mode. If you don't feel that you can carry out this procedure yourself, please get someone more experienced to help you.
>
> 1. Back up all data. There are ways to back up a computer that isn't fully functional. Ask if you need guidance. Don't skip this step.
> 2. Disconnect all external storage devices.
> 3. Start up in Recovery mode. Select a language, if prompted. The OS X Utilities screen will appear.
> 4. This step is only necessary if you use FileVault 2. If you don't know what FileVault is, you're not using it. Go to the next step. Otherwise, launch Disk Utility, then select the icon of the FileVault volume ("Macintosh HD," unless you gave it a different name.) It will be nested below another drive icon. Click the Unlock button in the toolbar and enter your login password when prompted. Then quit Disk Utility to be returned to the main screen.
> 5. Select Get Help Online. Safari will launch. While in Recovery, you'll have no access to your bookmarks, but you won't need them. Load this web page.
> 6. Triple-click anywhere in the line below to select it:
>    `chflags norestricted /V*/*/L*/Keyc*/*`
>    Copy the selected text to the Clipboard by pressing the key combination command-C.
> 7. Quit Safari. From the menu bar, select
>    Utilities ▹ Terminal
>    The Terminal application will launch. Paste into the Terminal window by pressing the key combination command-V. Wait for a new line ending in a dollar sign ($) to appear. Quit Terminal to be returned to the main screen.
> 8. Select
>     ▹ Restart
>    from the menu bar.
>    You should now be able to change or delete the file(s) in question.

Comment: I checked my user permissions on the related keychain file using the post above. I have read/write access to the file so that's not a solution for my case.

Comment: @SelcukS. Read/write permissions are separate from the `restricted` flag, and the `restricted` flag overrides normal permissions. So if you have read/write permissions for a file, but the file is `restricted`, you will *not* be able to modify it.